# jquery ui sortable, get sending object

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a two tables which items can sort/drop between both.
In my beforeStop method I am trying to access the sender, the element the item has come form  - but I am getting null.

http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-beforeStop

```
  $( "tbody" ).sortable({
            connectWith: "tbody",
            distance: 15,
            beforeStop: function(event, ui) {
                 console.log(ui.sender);
```

the console says

```
null
```

How can I get the element which the item has come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep the source container in a variable on the `start event`.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/XwxFz/1/)

```
var startElement = null;

$("#sortable").sortable(
    {
        start: function (event, ui) {
            startElement = $(this)
        },
        beforeStop: function(event, ui) {
            console.log(startElement);
        },
        connectWith: "#sortable2"
    }
);
```

Comment: Thats a hack. Introducing more state is not the answer.